# How to tell if a PHP session has timed out

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Currently I have been testing variables on $_SESSION, and if `isset()` returns false then assume the session has timed out to show a login page.

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['login'])):
  // Process login credentials
  $_SESSION['account'] = Array('user'=>'username');
endif;

if (! isset($_SESSION['account'])):
  // User not logged in, show login page
else:
  // User is logged in, show account page
endif;
```

However a user has recently reported that the account page was blank. I assume no session data was available because my code above is flawed somehow. Could someone point me in the right direction to correctly test if a session has timed out in PHP?

Comment: could it be a case of blank `$_SESSION['account']` variable? or may be it doesn't contains the expected value?

Comment: Ah yes you may be right! You prompted me to search the rest of the code and I discovered `$_SESSION['account'] = Array();` (although it *should* later be populated with account info, maybe that didn't happen). Is the rest of the above code fairly robust then?

Comment: If that is the case, you can also add another case to your if statement.  if(!isset($_SESSION['account']) || empty($_SESSION['account']))  That will check that the $_SESSION['account'] variable also does not contain the empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you could use:

```
if (! isset($_SESSION['account']) && !empty($_SESSION['account'])):
  // User not logged in, show login page
else:
  // User is logged in, show account page
endif;
```

so this wont pass for 2 conditions,

1. if session isn't set
2. if session is set, but is blank!

still a case exist of invalid values, for eg, username comes to `xyz` and you dont have any record matching `xyz`, then it could be a case of fetched no records and therefore it could be blank too!

so more than just these statements, you should have a further check that if the data in `$_POST` matched to any of your records in the systems, and only after the match is confirmed, you should set this in to `$_SESSION`.

And these should cover most of your cases, making escapes lesser!